# Suma de horas como doubles

Tags: java, android, jodatime

Tengo unos valores que tengo que sumar como horas, el problema reside en que estos valores me llegan como `double`, donde el primer numero es la hora y el segundo son los minutos, es decir, por ejemplo:

> valorA = 09.30 -> 9 horas y 30 minutos
>   valorB = 01.45 -> 1 hora y 45 minutos
>   valorTotal = valorA+ValorB

estoy usando `jodatime` haciendo lo siguiente

```
 LocalDateTime totalHoras = new LocalDateTime()
                        .withHourOfDay(0)
                        .withMinuteOfHour(0)
                        .withSecondOfMinute(0);

    Double value1 = entry1.getValue();
                            Double value2 = partesTrabajoIdHorasLocal.get(key);
                            String value1String = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(value1);
                            String value2String = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(value2);


                            totalHoras = totalHoras.plusHours(obtenerHoras(String.valueOf(value1String)));
                            totalHoras = totalHoras.plusMinutes(obtenerMinutos(String.valueOf(value2String)));

                            totalHoras = totalHoras.plusHours(obtenerHoras(String.valueOf(value1String)));
                            totalHoras = totalHoras.plusMinutes(obtenerMinutos(String.valueOf(value2String)));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero no me esta sumando las horas. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: No comprendo a que te refieres. Una hora y minutos te llegan en un double? que significa el valor `3.4545` ? 3 horas y 4545 minutos? no seran 3.4545 horas?

Comment: Si, es eso 3.45 horas ,  estoy viendo porque me llega  3.4545  ..... debería ser 3.45 ...

Comment: Entonces realiza `totalHoras.plusMinutes((int)(horas * 60))`

Comment: Los números te llegan como Double o como String?

Comment: me llegan como double

Comment: Respuesta actualizada para trabajar con `doubles`, `Doubles` o `Strings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un poco extraña la representación que se está usando para minutos y horas, pero bueno, si ese es el caso aquí están mis sugerencias:

- No uses SimpleDateFormat, joda time ya incluye formateadores de hora y fecha.
- Si puedes usar Java 8, utiliza java.time que es una versión mas nueva de joda-time que viene incluída con el JDK 8.
- No sumes los valores de tiempo cuando están en forma de Doubles, deja que la librería se encargue de ello.

Espero que el siguiente código te ayude:

```
    Double tiempoInicial = 9.30;
    Double tiempoAdicional = 1.45;

    String[] tiempo = String.format("%2.2f", tiempoInicial).split("\\.");
    int horas = Integer.valueOf(tiempo[0]);
    int minutos = Integer.valueOf(tiempo[1]);

    LocalDateTime totalHoras = new LocalDateTime()
            .withHourOfDay(horas)
            .withMinuteOfHour(minutos)
            .withSecondOfMinute(0)
            .withMillisOfSecond(0);
    System.out.printf("Hora inicial: %s\n", totalHoras.toString("HH:mm"));

    tiempo = String.format("%.2f", tiempoAdicional).split("\\.");
    horas = Integer.valueOf(tiempo[0]);
    minutos = Integer.valueOf(tiempo[1]);

    LocalDateTime tiempoFinal = totalHoras
            .plusHours(horas)
            .plusMinutes(minutos);

    System.out.printf("Hora final: %s\n", tiempoFinal.toString("HH:mm"));
```

Notas finales:

Sería ideal que la entrada llegara separada en sus componentes de hora y minutos o que viniera en forma de cadena propiamente formateada para que siempre exista el punto decimal. Tomando en cuenta esos detalles puedes usar todas o parte de las conversiones aquí mostradas.

Usar `doubles` para respresentar tiempo no es idóneo porque a veces los numeros pueden perder precisión como: 15 => 14.9999999999. Por eso es necesario adaptar los datos de entrada para que se adecúen a nuestro programa.